# How to convert "2012-01-03 12:50:49" to "108929"?

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, datetime-format

I am trying to get data from MySQL database and then insert it into my database. There is a column `Start_time` having the following value:

```
Start_time="2012-01-03 12:50:49"
```

The column next to it is `start_time_usec` and its value is:

```
start_time_usec="108929"
```

How is it converted to this format? How would I convert my datetime in to this format?

Comment: What is 108929 ? what is the relation between start_time and start_time_usec ??? Is it the seconds passed ?

Comment: can you explain it please? what is "`108929`"?

Comment: usec = micro seconds?  I have seen that some people use 'u' for 'μ' character. It seems first field stores the date and time with seconds, and the next field store the relevant micro seconds for the relevant timestamp.

Comment: there is a mysql function called date_format(wildcard)

Comment: @all if i would know what is it then why did i post this question here  ! thats why i told you the column name also what you guest i know just one thing that this is the start time of host ping request

Comment: @Manjula i think it would be microsecond..

Comment: @SalmanRaza I think there is no conversion you have to do between those two fields. It is just two separate fields for storing two separate parts of one property which is the starting time (For e.g: 2012-01-03 12:50:49.108929 is the start time). And AFAIK java date classes only provide times with milliseconds precision. Although you can get current system time in nano seconds. May be you will be able to manipulate that current time in nano seconds to get what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Given

```
start_time="2012-01-03 12:50:49";
start_time_usec="108929";
```

My assumption 
(From the logic I explained in previous comments

> Current timestamp is something like this 1325832619 (a number with 10
>   digits). If the value of the start_time_usec posted by OP (108929) is
>   an actual value currently stored inside his database, I think assuming
>   that field is the microsecond part (note that value is 6 digit number
>   which is required to represent micro seconds part) of the time is more
>   accurate than assuming it is the number of seconds from Unix epoch
>   (timestamp). Also 'usec' part gives a hint that 'u' actually means 'μ' character as in μs symbol which represents micro seconds.

)
is

```
start_time_with_micro_sec_precision = start_time + "." + start_time_usec;
```

In otherwords,

> **start_time_with_micro_sec_precision** for the given example values is **"2012-01-03 12:50:49.108929"**

So if you want to store it with micro seconds precision in the new database,
you can use the same way current database stored 
or you can concat above two values as I mentioned and store it in new mysql datetime field with micro seconds precision. Let the parsing of string to mysql function like [STR_TO_DATE(str,format)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

For example,

```
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ('field1', ... , STR_TO_DATE('2012-01-03 12:50:49.108929', '%Y-%m-%e %H:%i:%s.%f')
```

But the second approach may be not quite good if you need to use micro second part again in Java.

Comment: i want to convert "2012-01-03 12:50:49" in to this "108929" i am not getting what are you trying to tell me ?

Comment: Can you put the structure of your table in your post? According to your post you says you have a field(column) named "Start_time" and next to that column is a column named "start_time_usec". Am I correct? If so do you think there is a need in your current system to store "2012-01-03 12:50:49" and a value which can be converted directly from that same value again in another column? Or Do you actually mean in the post is that you have a java property named "start_time" and corresponding field in the database for that property is "start_time_usec"?

Comment: value which can be converted directly from that same value again in another column like i get "2012-01-03 12:50:49" will convert in to "108929" and then put it in the second column

Comment: Is this related to nagios database? If so, see the page 18 of http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/ndoutils/NDOUtils_DB_Model.pdf   it says start_time_usec is "The microsecond portion of the time the notification started."

Comment: yup you are right it is nagios database how would i change it to microsecond? pls

Comment: You cannot convert or derive microsecond part from the "Start_time" field. It is just that your database store the start time with the precision of a microsecond. For some practical reasons, developers of this system had decided to store microsecond part of the time separately. I think the reason is some programming languages doesn't support timestamps with microseconds easily. Therefore just find a way to get the microsecond part (it is not the number of microseconds from UNIX epoch, for example hour part is the hour) of the that time.

Answer (score 0):

I think the '108929' is the timestamp. So first you can parse string "2012-01-03 12:50:49" to a Date, then call Date.getTime() will return a 'long' value which is milliseconds.

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateformat1=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date d = dateformat1.parse("2012-01-03 12:50:49");
    long timestamp = d.getTime() / 1000;
```

Comment: 108929 seconds is about 30 hours -- there's no way to get a full date/time stamp out of that number.

Comment: i am getting "21325613049" after parsing the require date while the resuld would be "108929" ??

Comment: @donnior Current timestamp is something like this 1325832619  (a number with 10 digits). If the value of the start_time_usec posted by OP (108929) is an actual value currently stored inside his database, I think assuming that field is the microsecond part (note that value is 6 digit number which is required to represent micro seconds part) of the time is more accurate than assuming it is the number of seconds from Unix epoch (timestamp).

Comment: @Manjula then what should i do ?

Comment: donnior i am getting this value in the  column i mentioned and this is the time for host ping its start time and end time